# Conditional redirection in Django

Tags: python, django

I would like users to be conditionally redirected to different urls based on their email. So users who login with a specific email are redirected to page A and others to page B.

With the code i have currently, all users are redirected only to page A (google.com)

This is what I have in views.py

```
@login_required
@student_required
@check_is_allow
def messages(request):
    emails = ['aaa@gmail.com', 'aab@gmail.com', 'aac@gmail.com',
              'aba@gmail.com', 'abb@gmail.com', 'abc@gmail.com']
    if request.user.email in emails:
        return render(request, 'https://www.google.com/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'https://www.facebook.com/')
```

My urls.py

```
    ...
    path('messages', students.messages, name='messages'),
    ...
```

and html

```
...
<li><a href="{% url 'students:messages' %}">Messages</a></li>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`render` renders a template, it doesn't redirect users. Use the `redirect` shortcut to redirect users.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
if request.user.email in emails:
    return redirect("https://www.google.com")
```